# How to crossfade between two ngShow messages using css or ngAnimate

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show

I'm creating a form in angularjs in which there are two ngShow for error messages. Now, I want to crossfade these two messages placing them in the same spot. But, i'm not sure how to get it.

Here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/EcT2oOmClz65WUgXgG4g?p=preview

I'm using 1.2.4 and linked the ng-animate lib. Right now the animation (fading in/out) is achieved using CSS not JS:

html:

```
<input type="email"
       name="email"
       class="form-control"
       id="email"
       placeholder="Email"
       maxlength="100"
       title="Company issued email address"
       required
       ng-class=""
       ng-model="user.email"
       ng-blur="buyContactForm.email.$blured = true" />
```

css:

```
.errAnimate {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    min-height: 22px;
}    
.errAnimate.ng-show{
    opacity: 1;
}

.errAnimate.ng-show-add, .errAnimate.ng-show-remove {
    display:none!important;
}    
.errAnimate.ng-hide{
    opacity: 0;
}
.errAnimate.ng-hide-add, .errAnimate.ng-hide-remove {
    display:block!important;
}
```

JS:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.user={
        email: ''
    };
    $scope.showFieldError = function(formField, error, blured){
        if(blured){
            return formField.$error[error] && !formField.$pristine && formField.$blured;
        }else{
            return formField.$error[error] && !formField.$pristine;
        }
    };
    // set live validation function for view load mode
    $scope.showError = $scope.showFieldError;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you can do it is by adding *position: absolute* to the container's style, like this:

```
.errAnimate {
    position: absolute;

    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    min-height: 22px;
}
```

This will make both errors have the same position while fading, and thus overlapping (which is what I think you mean by crossfading)

I also had to change the width of the container because its width was making the error messages span several lines.

[Here is a link to the edited plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqZnrC66Vi6AhJ9D7nXS?p=preview)